# Is it possible to use VB project as an Endpoint in n-service bus solution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, nservicebus, endpoint

Is it possible to use VB project as an Endpoint in n-service bus solution? When I add an endpoint - "Nservice Bus Web EndPoint" it automatically creates it as a C# project.
I want it to be Visual Basic project. Is this possible? Also, if I have already have a Visual Basic project created inside my Nservice bus solution, how can I add it as an Endpoint?

Comment: NSB Studio doesn't support the creation of VB projects. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NServiceBus endpoints can be a class library running off NServiceBus Host. The Host is just an executable (.exe file) that would run your class library with which you can switch very easily from console app in dev/test environment to a Windows Service in Production. So technically speaking there's really no limitation on the Language that you can use in a NServiceBus solution, but since the default template is only C# you need to set this up yourself. Do the following steps to run your VB.NET project as an NServiceBus endpoint:

1. Create a new (or use existing) VB.NET class library.
2. Add NServiceBus libraries to the references
3. Add NServiceBus host (.exe file) to the references
4. Compile the solution and select the Host executable as the debugging assembly in Project setting. This will ensure the executable is run when you debug the solution.
5. Add a class implementing IConfigureThisEndPoint.
6. Make the class also implement a role (e.g. AsA_Server) that would make sense for your scenario.

Now by running/debugging your class library a console app should pop up with logs and everything else.